# How to stop request to website till cache is being built

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7

I am working on website which stores important data in HTTPContext.Cache for fast performance. If any data is changed during the day time. we have automated process to clear and regenerate the cache. But the problem is when cache is getting generated any user trying to access the website gets error.

I am looking for a solution to this problem. Where i can stop the request to website till cache generation is not finished.

One is to put app_offline file and delete it when cache is fully refreshed.

Please do let me know if you need more information

Comment: What exception does your website throw? How big is your cache, and how long does it take to create it?

Comment: Its throws error like data not found as the data is still built up in cache. The cache not too big but to clean and create takes about 90 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `global.asax` and do something like

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(fCacheIsNotReady)
   {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("We not build our site, please try again in few seconds.");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
   }    
}
```

The `fCacheIsNotReady` can be global static parametre that is true, when you start build you cache, and false when you end,
You can also check what files are you going to stop.

I do not know how you create your cache, you may also use some `lock()` to hold the users until the cache is made.